# Showing charts while going through PHP IF loop

Tags: php, html, charts

I'm working on showing the data from the DB using html table and google charts.
In one part of the script im using an IF loop,that is very important.It operates the things that's gonna be shown on the screen.But the IF loop doesn't work like it should be.

```
<?php if($IF==3){ ?>


<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div id="first" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div id="second" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div id="third" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
} else if($IF==2){ ?>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div id="first" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div id="second" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
<?php }else{?>      

<div class='row'>   
    <div class='col-md-12'>         
        <div id="first" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div> 
    </div>

</div>  

<?php } ?>
```

Let's explain what i wanted to do here.If the variable $IF equals 3 (number of employees) it shows 3 pie charts,and this part works.It shows the right data and the right amount of pie charts.
But the problem appears when $IF<2.
The pie charts won't show.
Am i doing this the wrong way?
Thx in advance.

Comment: What are you using to display the charts with?

Comment: I'm using google charts https://developers.google.com/chart/

the chart is prepared in the <head> tag of the page,and then i just call the script with `<div id="first" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>`

Comment: Seems to work fine when manually setting $IF this side, have you printed out $IF to make sure the value is correct?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in Javascript console? Maybe the reason is that there are no elements with ID=first  or ID=second that are expected to exist by the chart code.

Comment: Yes i did,even tryed to delete the fist part of the loop,still won't work.
Before the loop,i also have a chart that displays the general data,and when the problem happens,he won't show either.

this is what i got in the console
 **Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table).**

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem,when I was creating the charts for 3 employees i had to send 3 different types of data in the script.BUT,when there were only 2 or 1 employee the variables that saved the data for the second or third were empty,and that created an error.It couldn't create a chart when the variables were empty.So i just added a simple IF loop to manage that